# When an unregistered user submits a form for a custom post type, send an email that lets them delete their post

Tags: custom-post-types

I want visitors to submit a form (created with CRED, but could use Gravity Forms or Formidable Pro if that helps) that submits a custom post type that's immediately published. I know how to do this.

When the post is published, I want the unregistered visitor who submitted the form to receive an email with a link (I'm assuming with some kind of md5 code) that will allow them to delete the post they created. Just like how Craigslist sends unregistered users a link to edit/delete their post. But I just need it to delete the post.

I've read through this thread ([When a user creates a post (pending), send a confirmation link that allows them to publish](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113019/when-a-user-creates-a-post-pending-send-a-confirmation-link-that-allows-them)) and see it going the other way, I'm just not sure how to adapt it to delete.

Comment: Should be very similar to [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109680/73).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publish Post After Click On A Link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109676/publish-post-after-click-on-a-link)